# Embedded Signing - Rendering a docusign document in an iframe is taking around 10 seconds to display

Tags: docusignapi

Observed the Integration APIs (Token Creation, Envelope Creation, Receipient View Creation) itself taking ~5-6seconds & the rest of the time in loading the docusign page in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This may be normal, it depends on the amount of data (size of documents) and how busy DocuSign servers are.
You don't have to block the UI right away, when you create the envelope and make the next API call, you can have the UI ready, do this in the background and prepare everything and then show it to the user. This way you avoid the 10 seconds delay that, I agree, is not an ideal user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Inbar. I am using a sample document only. As you said, waiting for 5-10seconds to get the docusign UI loaded doesn't seem to be a good user experience.